# Count a string of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have something like this

```
all stuffs = {
 "stuff": "[11:22:33, dd:34:11, 11:33:44, 33:ff:ee]"
}
```

How can I find the length of this stuff? 
I use stuff.length, it counts every single letter including : and , in that string.

Comment: That's what length does

Comment: what do you want to count then?

Comment: the length of "this stuff".  Can you be *any* more specific?

Comment: post your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: Try `console.log(stuffs.stuff.split(',').length)`

Comment: i try to get the length of the stuff which is 4. But I have like 37 if I use stuff.length

Comment: Thanks @NenadVracar. Thats what I need.

Comment: @Tenz because your `stuff` value is `string` not `array`. If your want to treat it as `array` then do as Nenad Vracar suggested.

Answer (score 2):

stuff is stored as a string and not an array. use `split(,)` to split the string inside stuff on commas and then count.

```js
var all_stuffs = {
 "stuff": "[11:22:33, dd:34:11, 11:33:44, 33:ff:ee]"
};

console.log(all_stuffs.stuff.replace(/[]/g, "").split(",").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

splitting on "," allows to take the length

```
all_stuff.stuff.split(',').length
```